# error phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, apache, xampp

instale el xampp 7.3.7; al incio tuve algun problema para levantar el servicio asi que elimine los archivos de **\xampp\mysql\data** ibdata1,ib_logfile1.. etc todos menos las carpetas no tenia ninguna ninguna informacion que perder.. acabe cambiandole el puerto a 3366 y me levanta el servicio correctamente.. incluso añadi datos con ***mySQL Worbench*** pero a la hora de tratar de abrir el **phpMyAdmin** me muestra el error de la foto..

[image: error al abrir el admin de phpMyAdmin]

> - mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> - La conexión para controluser, como está definida en su configuración, fracasó.
> - mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>     'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> - phpMyAdmin intentó conectarse
>     con el servidor MySQL, y el servidor rechazó esta conexión. Deberá revisar el host, nombre de usuario y contraseña en config.inc.php y asegurarse que corresponden con la información provista por el
>     administrador del servidor MySQL

estaban como por defecto 'root' sin pass, probe cambiar la configuracion de **my.ini** y de **config.inc.php** habilitando la opcion de pasword y poniendo uno sencillo pero nada.. Saludos

Comment: verifica el puerto de conexion de phpmyadmin a mysql dado que no está actualizado y verifica $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3366';

Comment: @DavidSantos si me funciono... era eso gracias amigo

Comment: te posteo el comentario como respuesta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

verifica el puerto de conexion de phpmyadmin a mysql dado que no está actualizado y verifica

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3366';
```

Comment: Si era esto al cambiar el puerto de MySQL se debe cambiar tambien en la configuracion config.ini.php habia probado poniendo el puerto 3366 en el navegador pero asi no funcionaba..

Answer (score 2):

Tenía el mismo error luego de intentar cambiar el password a MySQL User = root y Password = root. Luego de esto me salió ese error; Lo solucioné editando el archivo:

c:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc

y cambiando la linea

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

por:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me funcionó perfecto...

Espero te sirva y salgas del problema...

Answer (score 1):

Para poder acceder a través de phpmyadmin y que pida el usuario y contraseña, los parámetros de `config.inc.php` de phpmyadmin deben estar:

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Comment: Me funciona parcialmente cuando pongo:>$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; paso la ventana del error... pero no me deja entrar con la contraseña que tengo en el my.ini ademas de la del config.ini.php sabes que puede ser

Comment: Editanto $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true; y poniendo $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3366' con el puerto entro al phpMyAdmin con root pass ´´

Answer (score 0):

This previous three solutions didn't worked for me. This one did:

**1.** As mentioned above, in "C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php", change the following values and save the file:

**1.1.**
"$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';"
by
"$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';"

**1.2.**
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
by
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'SomePasswordThatYouWant';

**1.3.**
"$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;"
by
"$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;"

**Note:** Remember that the defaul user will be "root". After saving this settings, you'll access phpmyadmin by specifying "root" as the username and the value that you privided in "$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']" as the password.

**2.** Open the XAMPP Control Panel.

**3.** Stop Apache and MySQL by pressing the stop button under the "Actions" column in the XAMPP Control Panel.

**4.** In the MySQL row, press the "Config" button, and then select the "my.ini" option (other option is to open this file in this location: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini).

**5.** Find the line that says "[mysqld]" and add the following text right bellow of that "[mysqld]" line: "skip-grant-tables".

And done! This solved my problem without data loss.

I found this solution in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzs9Z12OTE4 At 2023-11-8.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/398067)